# Disable dropzone page refresh

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, dropzone.js

I have been searching for a few days and have found multiple solutions how to reload page after upload and so on.  My issue is that after an upload the page automatically reloads and I do not want this.

I am not sure what I am missing here but this is a pretty standard setup from dropzone home page.

```
function initDropzone() {


    var dz = new Dropzone('#fupld', {
        url: 'upload',
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        paramName: 'files',
        autoDiscover:false,
        init: function () {
            this.on('queuecomplete', () => {
            }),
                this.on('success', function (file, response) {
            });
            this.on('error', (file, response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    });
}


<form class="fupld" action="@Url.Action("upload")" id="fupld" method="post">
    <div class="dz-message">Upload</div>
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</form>
```

Everything is done as expected.  Files are uploaded, errors are displayed etc.

The only thing that I am trying to work around is the fact that after the successful upload the page refreshes and I don't want this.

My server side always returns Json and there is no redirect anywhere.

I have tried to hook into submit event and call preventDefault along with calling the dropzone disable() after successful upload but the page still refreshes.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Note this is using .NET to upload.

Comment: Could you show your hmtl code ?

Comment: @ToujouAya Done

Answer (score 4):

I'm super late to this party... but for me, i was facing the same issue.  after post my page was refreshing... the issue turned out to be that the button i was using to start the upload didn't have type="button" so ultimately the dropzone post was running, as well as the button doing a normal submit on the form!

this only occurs if you are using your own form as the dropzone (so that you can post other inputs too).

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and this fixed for me as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was struggling with a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone who might be facing the same issue.

After constant changes to javascript adding/removing modifying event handlers and other functions turns out the problem was the fact that BrowserLink was turned on in Visual Studio.  Once I turned off BrowserLink all seems to be ok, so it seems that browserlink reloads the page after a 200 response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to stopPropagation on the event? together with the preventDefault https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```js
const {getRootProps} = useDropzone({noDragEventsBubbling: true});
```

More info [here](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#!/Event%20Propagation)

Comment: Your solution is only for react and not native javascript, it will hardly help.